# How can I reference column aliases from a projection inside the projection?

Tags: sql-standard, projection

Calculations on the projection (`select`) values are  useful and common. Yet column aliases declared in the projection can't be used there.

```
select sellprice as x, cost as y, x/y as markup  
from mytable
```

gives an error.

I can accomplish this with

```
select sellprice as x, cost as y, sellprice/cost as markup  
from mytable
```

But that is a simple example: We usually declare column aliases names with `as` for complex cases. For example, instead of `cost`, I might have some  function built from `average` etc,  that I declare as a column alias.

How can I use these aliases inside the projection clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to cope with that is to use a derived table (aka sub-query):

```
select x, y, x/y as markup
from (
  select sellprice as x, cost as y
  from mytable
) as t;
```

Comment: Thank you. Any insights on  why SQL requires this workaround where select `sellprice as x, cost as y, x/y as markup   from mytable` seems to make more sense?

Comment: @JoshuaFox: that's how the SQL syntax was defined. You would need to ask the SQL standard committee for _why_ that decision was taken. My guess(!!) is that using "forward" references was simply deemed to be too complicated for parsers back in  70's

Comment: @JoshuaFox, renaming ( as ) happens last. Note that the DBMS is free to change the order of evaluation, as long as the semantics are preserved. In a query (though stupid) like `select x as y, y as x, x/y from t` the order in which renaming happens matters.